# Extjs4 space issue while using menu.menu

Tags: menu, extjs4

i am working in extjs. I have view as=

```
Ext.define('a.b.searchPanel',{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',    
alias : 'widget.searchpanel',

me.items = [{
            xtype: 'container',
            height: 40,
            layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
            items : [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        itemId: 'keywordtextField',
                        fieldLabel:
                        labelAlign : 'right',
                        name: 'field1',
                        labelWidth:80,
                        padding: '5 30 0 30',
                        width:265
                     },{
                        xtype: 'image',
                        margin: '8 0 0 0',
                        width: 14,
                        src :'../../UI-INF/images/form/icon-question.png',
                        listeners: {
                            afterrender : function(img, eOpts){
                                img.el.on('mouseover', function() {});
                            }
                        }
                 }]
          },{
            xtype: 'combo',
            itemId: 'tagsCombo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            padding: '5 10 0 115',
            store:searchPanelTagStore,
            width: 180,
            multiSelect: true,
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'id',

       },{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        padding: '10 30 0 10'
                    },
                    defaults:{
                        margins: '0 30 0 10'
                    },
            items : [{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                name: 'searchStartdate',
                labelWidth:90,
                labelAlign: 'right',
                itemId: 'searchPanelStartdate'
            },{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                name: 'searchClosedate',
                itemId: 'searchPanelClosedate'
            }]
        },
})
```

This above view i have included as xtype in=

```
menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
                    id: 'searchMenu',
                    margin:'0 0 0 0',
                    padding:'0 0 0 0',
                    items: [{
                        xtype:'searchpanel',
                        width: 500,
                        id: 'search-panel',                             
                        height: 300
                    }]
```

This screen is appearing as=[image]
As i am using menu.menu, my searchpanel view is having space margin on left side. So how to remove this space? I want all fields at left side in view

Answer (score 0):

apply following css. It will work with Ext js 4.2

```
.no-icon-menu .x-menu-item-icon {
    display: none; 
}
  Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
                    id: 'searchMenu',
                    margin:'0 0 0 0',
                    padding:'0 0 0 0',
                    iconCls : 'no-icon-menu',
                    items: [{
                        xtype:'searchpanel',
                        width: 500,
                        id: 'search-panel',                             
                        height: 300
                    }]
```